# android app crashes on clicking the button for the second time

Tags: android, rss

I created a simple app to display nasa's image of the day from its rss feed. now i created a refresh button that would show a progress dialog box and then refresh the page. it works fine when clicked for the first time but the app stops when it is clicked the next time.

the method refreshform is called when the button is clicked. this the thread created (in onCreate method and is named first)....

private void refreshForm()
    {

```
     dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            this,
            "Loading",
            "Loading the image of the Day");


                //resetDisplay(handler.getTitle(),handler.getDate(),handler.getImage(),handler.getDescription());




    th.start();
/*  IotdHandler handler = new IotdHandler();
    handler.processFeed();
    resetDisplay(handler.getTitle(),handler.getDate(),handler.getImage(),handler.getDescription());*/

}


public void run()
{                   
    if(Thread.currentThread().getName()=="first")
    {
    if(handler==null)
    {       
     handler = new IotdHandler();
    }
    handler.processFeed();

    handle.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            resetDisplay(handler.getTitle(),handler.getDate(),handler.getImage(),handler.getDescription());
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    }
    else if(Thread.currentThread().getName()=="second")
    {
        WallpaperManager wp= WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        try
        {
            wp.setBitmap(wallpaper);
            handle.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Start.this, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

                    );
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            handle.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Start.this, "Error Setting Wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

                    );

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the LogCat with the error the crash is giving

Answer (score 0):

it good to past your logcat 
but I guess your problem is this code on 2nd thread

```
Toast.makeText(Start.this, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

you can not add Toast on none UI thread

you can Handler to do that